# unexpected token error in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

Hello I am currently getting these errors on the chrome console. The one I want to solve is the Uncaught SyntaxError. It shows as being on the line 'useCSS' in my javascript and I have no idea why as everything works ok still.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/js/plugins/jquery.fitvids.js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : VM107 index2.html:17
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS http://player.vimeo.com/video/110194991

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
video: true,
useCSS: false,
pager: false,
controls: false
});
</script>
```

Can somebody see why I am getting this Unexpected Token error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your JavaScript is malformed. It should probably be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        video: true,
        useCSS: false,
        pager: false,
        controls: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send video, useCss etc as an object to bxSlider(), like this:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    video: true,
    useCSS: false,
    pager: false,
    controls: false
});
```